# Timefield hideMode visibility

Tags: extjs

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5do

```
items:[{
    xtype:'timefield',
    id:'time',
    hideMode:'visibility'
},{
    xtype:'checkbox',
    labelText:'hide',
    listeners:{
        change:function(cmp,nv) {
            console.log('Checkchange');
            if(nv) Ext.getCmp("time").hide();
            else Ext.getCmp("time").show();
        }
    }
}]
```

I'm using `hideMode:'visibility'` but TimeField does `display:hidden`.

Did I do error in code, or is this bug in ExtJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ExtJS.

The "hidden component is considered hidden so it won't participate in a layout, regardless of the hideMode".

This has been reported as a bug at least twice that I could find, but apparently the developers decided this is what they intended.

See this bug report for the details: [hideMode: "visibility" not working for toolbar items?](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?283553-hideMode-quot-visibility-quot-not-working-for-toolbar-items)
See this also: [BUG: hideMode=visibility does not work for hbox](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?271686-BUG-hideMode-visibility-does-not-work-for-hbox)

If you still want to do it though, here is the **workaround** proposed in the first thread:

```
component.el.setStyle('visibility', 'hidden');
```